# Poker probabilities finder

Tags: python, performance, random, playing-cards, simulation

This code finds the probabilities of the various scores in Poker. It uses a [Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) approach, in which, two million (\$2 \times 10^{6}\$) hands are simulated and evaluated, not an exhaustive search.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands), my results are accurate.

I strived to avoid over-engineering, where the only tricky part is `poker_value` as it uses a bit of metaprogramming, but it was necessary to avoid duplication.

I am interested in performance improvements *only if* they do not hurt readability and straightforwardness.

An example output is:

```
Poker probabilities:
('nothing', 50.1837)
('pair', 42.1968)
('two_pair', 4.77195)
('three_of_a_kind', 2.18145)
('straight', 0.3568)
('flush', 0.198)
('full_house', 0.08485)
('four_of_a_kind', 0.02505)
('straight_flush', 0.0014)
Time taken: 107.4311831
```

The code:

```
from __future__ import division
from collections import namedtuple, Counter
import doctest
import random
import time

CARDS_PER_HAND = 5
VALUES = 13
KINDS = 4
ACCURACY = 2 * 10 ** 6

Card = namedtuple("Card", ["value", "kind"])

def all_equal(lst):
    """
    >>> all_equal([1,1,1,1])
    True
    >>> all_equal([1,2,3])
    False
    """
    return len(set(lst)) == 1

def couples(lst):
    """
    >>> couples([1,5,7])
    [[1, 5], [5, 7]]
    """
    return [ [curr, lst[index + 1]]
                   for index, curr in enumerate(lst[:-1])]

def one_by_one_increasing(lst):
    """
    >>> one_by_one_increasing([5, 6, 7, 8])
    True
    """
    return all(nexxt == previous + 1
                   for previous, nexxt in couples(lst))

def most_common(lst):
    """
    >>> most_common([1,2,2,2,3])
    2
    """
    return Counter(lst).most_common()[0][0]

def most_common_count(lst):
    """
    >>> most_common_count([4,4,4,1,1])
    3
    >>> most_common_count([7,3,1,7,8])
    2
    """
    return lst.count(most_common(lst))

def first_true(arg, funcs):
    """
    >>> def false(n): return False
    >>> def even(n): return n % 2 == 0
    >>> first_true(14, [false, even]).__name__
    'even'
    """
    for f in funcs:
        if f(arg):
            return f

def values(cards):
    """
    >>> values([ Card(12, 3), Card(5, 2), Card(8, 3)])
    [12, 5, 8]
    """
    return [c.value for c in cards]

def kinds(cards):
    """
    >>> kinds([ Card(12, 2), Card(5, 3)])
    [2, 3]
    """
    return [c.kind for c in cards]

def is_straight_flush(hand):
    """
    >>> is_straight_flush(Card(x, 2) for x in range(4, 9))
    True
    """
    return is_flush(hand) and is_straight(hand)

def is_flush(hand):
    """
    >>> is_flush(Card(x, 2) for x in [3,6,1,10])
    True
    """
    return all_equal(kinds(hand))

def is_four_of_a_kind(hand):
    """
    >>> is_four_of_a_kind([ Card(5, 2), Card(5, 3), Card(5, 1), Card(5, 4), Card(8, 3) ])
    True
    """
    return most_common_count(values(hand)) == 4

def is_three_of_a_kind(hand):
    """
    >>> is_three_of_a_kind( [Card(12, 2)]*3 + [Card(2, 3), Card(9, 2)])
    True
    >>> is_three_of_a_kind( [Card(2, 1), Card(3, 2), Card(3, 1), Card(5, 1), Card(9, 4)] )
    False
    """
    return most_common_count(values(hand)) == 3

def is_pair(hand):
    """
    >>> is_pair( [Card(2, 1), Card(3, 2), Card(3, 1), Card(5, 1), Card(9, 4)] )
    True
    """
    return most_common_count(values(hand)) == 2

def is_straight(hand):
    """
    >>> is_straight( [Card(value, random.randint(0,4)) for value in range(0,5)] )
    True
    """
    return one_by_one_increasing(sorted(values(hand)))

def is_two_pair(hand):
    """
    >>> is_two_pair([Card(1, 1), Card(3, 2), Card(3, 1), Card(9, 1), Card(9, 4)])
    True
    >>> is_two_pair( [Card(2, 1), Card(3, 2), Card(3, 1), Card(5, 1), Card(9, 4)] )
    False
    """
    return is_pair(hand) and is_pair([c for c in hand if c.value != most_common(values(hand))])

def is_full_house(hand):
    """
    >>> is_full_house([Card(3, 1), Card(3, 2), Card(3, 1), Card(9, 1), Card(9, 4)])
    True
    """
    return is_three_of_a_kind(hand) and is_pair([c for c in hand if c.value != most_common(hand).value])

def is_nothing(hand):
    """
    A hand is always at least nothing
    >>> is_nothing(Card(random.randint(0,12), random.randint(0,3)) for _ in range(CARDS_PER_HAND))
    True
    """
    return True

def poker_value(hand, possible_scores=[is_straight_flush, is_four_of_a_kind, is_full_house,
                        is_flush, is_straight, is_three_of_a_kind, is_two_pair, is_pair, is_nothing]):
    """
    >>> poker_value([ Card(5, 1), Card(7, 2), Card(9, 3), Card(10, 1), Card(10, 1) ])
    'pair'
    >>> poker_value([ Card(val, 3) for val in range(2, 7)])
    'straight_flush'
    """
    return first_true(hand, possible_scores).__name__[3:]

def poker_deck(max_value=VALUES, number_of_kinds=KINDS):
    """
    >>> len(poker_deck())
    52
    """
    return [ Card(value, kind)
                 for value in range(max_value)
                     for kind in range(number_of_kinds)]

def poker_percentages(accuracy):
    deck = poker_deck()
    occurencies = Counter( poker_value(random.sample(deck, CARDS_PER_HAND))
                        for _ in range(accuracy))
    return list(sorted(((name, round((occurencies[name] / accuracy * 100), CARDS_PER_HAND) )
                           for name in occurencies), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

def main():
    start = time.time()
    print("Poker probabilities:")
    print("\n".join(map(str, poker_percentages(ACCURACY))))
    print("Time taken: {}".format(time.time() - start))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
    main()
```

Comment: Does this code recognize that (T, J, Q, K, A) and (A, 2, 3, 4, 5) are both valid straights?  I.e., that for purposes of a straight, an ace can be both high and low?

Comment: Ace is only considered in the lower straight for  simplicity of implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks good and the logic is well separated in testable (and tested) functions.

A few details :

- Maybe it would make sense for `all_equal(lst)` to return True for an empty list (just like the `all` builtin returns True for empty iterable). You'd just need to replace `== 1` by `<= 1`.
- In `couples`, you are using explicitely the index to iterate over consecutive arrays. You'll find [various other ways to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303224/iterate-over-all-pairs-of-consecutive-items-from-a-given-list). I'll let you pick the one you prefer (after performing some benchmark if needed). Also, because of the way you use it, there might not be a need for returning a newly constructed list, an iterable would be enough.
- Your implemement of `most_common` should pass 1 as a parameter to `most_common` so that it doesn't generate the whole list so that you are mostly ignoring.
- Your implementation of `most_common_count` is not really efficient : the `most_common()` function already returns the count and you are simply ignoring it.

I think the right way to do it would be to have a most_common() function returning a tuple `(item, count)`. Also you should probably handle the cases where different items are the most common.

I'll try to continue.